# Adding dynamic content to dynamic content. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web-applications

I'm creating a quiz website for a class, and I am having trouble formatting the page where the user creates questions. I would like to have additional information pertaining a specific question type pop up when the user clicks a radio button. I would then like to have even more additional information pop up if the user clicks a button created in the initial additional information.

So it'd start off looking like this

[image: initial display]

then it'd look like this

[image: display after additional information added]

then once the user clicked the Add Option button a few times, it'd look like this

[image: display after more information added]

To achieve this I am trying to use jquery to add the new content. However, I can't seem to get that content to display. Here's the current code

**In jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="QuestionsCreate.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz Creation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Your Quiz</h1>

    <form action="QuestionsCreateServlet" method="post">
        <h2>Question Type</h2>

        <input type="radio" name="type" class="type" id="multipleChoice"
            value="multipleChoice" />
        <label for="multipleChoice">Multiple Choice</label><br/>

        <input type="radio" name="type" class="type" id="fillBlank"
            value="fillBlank" />
        <label for="fillBlank">Fill-in-the-Blank</label><br/>

        <input type="radio" name="type" class="type" id="pictureResponse"
            value="pictureResponse" />
        <label for="pictureRsponse">Picture Response</label><br/>

        <input type="radio" name="type" class="type" id="textResponse"
            value="textResponse" />
        <label for="textResponse">Text Response</label><hr/>

        <div class="jspf"></div>

        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Finish" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**In javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".type").click(function(){
    $(".jspf").html("<jsp:include page='WEB-INF/" +
            $(".type").attr("value") + ".jspf' />");
    $("#button").attr("value", "Add");
    });

    var nOptions = 1;
    $("#add-option").click(function(){
    ++nOptions;
    $(".options").append("<input type='checkbox' name='option" +
            nOptions + "' value='" + nOptions + "' /> " +
            "<input name='name" + nOptions + "' /><br />");
    });

    var nBlanks = 1;
    $("#add-answer").click(function() {
    ++nBlanks;
    $(".fill-blank-answer").append("<input name='answer" + nBlanks +
            "' /><br/>");
    });
});
```

**Sample jspf**

```
<h3>Question</h3>
<input name="prompt" />
<h3>Options</h3>
Check the options that denote the correct answer<br/>
<div class="options">
<input type='checkbox' name='option1' value='1' />
<input name='name1' /><br />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Option" id="add-option" /><hr/>
```

I've also tried to move the jspf code into the javascript, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way I can add content dynamically to my webpage based off of dynamically added content? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Of course not, you'll tear a hole in the space–time continuum and life as we know it will cease to exist. Granted that's a worst case scenario—on the other hand it may just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is you're trying to inject server-side JSP tags into a client's browser.  Take this line for example:

```
$(".jspf").html("<jsp:include page='WEB-INF/" +
        $(".type").attr("value") + ".jspf' />");
```

Once that line of javascript has executed, the CLIENT's brower now has the markup:

```
<div class="jspf"><jsp:include page="wEB-INF/pictureResponse.jspf" /></div>
```

Broswers don't know what to do with <jsp:include> tags, so they just silently ignore them.

What you need to do is map the jspf you're trying to include to a url and use something like:

```
$(".jspf").load("/fragments/pictureResponse.jspf");
```

[$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) sends an AJAX request to from the client browser back to the server, retrieves a bit of HTML from the server, then inserts that in to the elements that match the CSS selector ".jspf".

You also have an issue with your initial click handler.

```
$(".type").attr("value")
```

[$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) always returns the attribute value of the first matched element, so no matter what the user clicked, that line is going to evaluate to "multipleChoice".  What you probably want to do is:

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

In the context of a click handler, "this" is going to refer to what the user just clicked.

**UPDATE**

Here's how I would add the "add option" click handler once the secondary content has been loaded:

```
$('jspf').load('/fragments/pictureResponse.jspf', function() {
    $('#add-option').click(function() {
        nOptions++;
        $('.options').append('<input type="checkbox" name="option' + nOptions +
        '" value="' + nOptions + '" />  <input name="name' + nOptions + '" /><br />");
    });
});
```

Comment: That works on the initial dynamic content. I was able to produce the same results by putting everything in the javascript. How do I get the secondary dynamic content loaded? Is that part possible?

Comment: The issue you're probably having with the secondary content is you're attempting to attach the event handler to a DOM element before the element actually exists, since you're trying to attach the handlers in the document.ready event.  What I would recommend is to use the second parameter to $.load(), which is a callback that will be executed once the AJAX request has completed.  Once you're executing that callback the new elements will be in the documents DOM, so you can add your new event handlers there.

Answer (score 1):

$.get("${ctx}/store/terminalApply/applyTemplate?terminalType=${terminalType}&index="+num, function(data){
            $("#contentDiv").append(data);
        });

data was a page content

Comment: should ${terminalType} be inside the double quotes?